# Build histogram

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to make histogram by python. I am starting with the following snippet:

```
def histogram(L):
    d = {}
    for x in L:
        if x in d:
            d[x] += 1
        else:
            d[x] = 1
    return d
```

I understand it's using dictionary function to solve the problem.
But I'm just confused about the 4th line: `if x in d:`

d is to be constructed, there's nothing in d yet, so how come if x in d?

Comment: If you  look for a histogram then use the histogram functions from numpy/scipy or matplotlib. Libraries are great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside of the `for` loop will be executed once for each element in `L`, with `x` being the value of the current element.

Lets look at the simple case where `L` is the list `[3, 3]`.  The first time through the loop `d` will be empty, `x` will be 3, and `3 in d` will be false, so `d[3]` will be set to 1.  The next time through the loop `x` will be 3 again, and `3 in d` will be true, so `d[3]` will be incremented by 1.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind, that `if` is inside a `for` loop.

So, when you're looking at the very first item in `L` there is nothing in `d`, but when you get to the next item in `L`, there **is** something in `d`, so you need to check whether to make a new bin on the histogram (`d[x] = 1`), or add the item to an existing bin (`d[x] += 1`).

In Python, we actually have some shortcuts for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def histogram(L):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for x in L:
        d[x] += 1
return d
```

This automatically starts each bin in `d` at zero (what `int()` returns) so you don't have to check if the bin exists. On Python 2.7 or higher:

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter(L)
```

Will automatically make a mapping of the frequencies of each item in `L`. No other code required.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a histogram with a dict comprehension:

```
histogram = {key: l.count(key) for key in set(L)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the other guys have explained you why `if x in d`. But here is a clue, how this code should be written following "don't ask permission, ask forgiveness":

```
    ...
    try:
        d[x] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[x] = 1
```

The reason for this, is that you expect this error to appear only once (at least once per method call). Thus, there is no need to check if `x in d`.

Comment: `except` is much slower than `if`, but `try` is faster -- so if `if x not in d` is going to happen fairly frequently, it's better to ask permission. When the `KeyError` is truly the __except__ ional case, then you should use `try` / `except` and just ask forgiveness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), available from Python 2.7 and Python 3.1+.

```
>>> # init empty counter
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()

>>> # add a single sample to the histogram
>>> c.update([4])
>>> # add several samples at once
>>> c.update([4, 2, 2, 5])

>>> # print content
>>> print c

Counter({2: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1})
```

The module brings several nice features, like addition, subtraction, intersection and union on counters. The `Counter` can count anything which can be used as a dictionary key.

Answer (score 0):

if x isn't in d, then it gets put into d with d[x] = 1. Basically, if x shows up in d more than once it increases the number matched with x.

Try using this to step through the code: http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own histogram in Python using for example `matplotlib`. If you want to see one example about how this could be implemented, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496996/832621).

[image]

In this specific case, you can use doing:

```
temperature = [4,   3,   1,   4,   6,   7,   8,   3,   1]
radius      = [0,   2,   3,   4,   0,   1,   2,  10,   7]
density     = [1,  10,   2,  24,   7,  10,  21, 102, 203]

points, sub = hist3d_bubble(temperature, density, radius, bins=4)
sub.axes.set_xlabel('temperature')
sub.axes.set_ylabel('density')
sub.axes.set_zlabel('radius')
```